# SQL help - find the table that has 'somefieldId' as the primary key?

Tags: sql, sql-server, search

How can I search my sql database for a table that contains a field `tiEntityId`. This field is referenced in a stored procedure, but I am unable to identify which table this id is a primary key for? Any suggestions? I currently look through stored procedure definitions for references to text by using something like this:

```
Declare @Search varchar(255)
SET @Search='[10.10.100.50]'

SELECT DISTINCT
o.name AS Object_Name,o.type_desc
FROM sys.sql_modules        m 
    INNER JOIN sys.objects  o ON m.object_id=o.object_id
WHERE m.definition Like '%'+@Search+'%'
ORDER BY 2,1
```

Any SQL guru's out there know what I need to use to find the table that contains the field, preferably the table where that field is the Primary Key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for primary keys that contain a column with a given name (in SQL 2005+), here you go:

```
select so.name as TableName,
       si.name as IndexName,
       sc.name as ColumnName
  from sys.indexes si
  join sys.index_columns sic
    on si.object_id = sic.object_id
   and si.index_id = sic.index_id
  join sys.columns sc
    on si.object_id = sc.object_id
   and sic.column_id = sc.column_id
  join sys.objects so
    on si.object_id = so.object_id
 where sc.name like '%ColumnName%'
   and si.is_primary_key = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
select table_name
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where column_name = 'MyColumn'
```